# How to convert a union of tuples to an object type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type `InputData` which is either `string` or a tuple. I want to transform it to object.

```
type InputType = File | string | boolean;
type InputData = string | [string, InputType]

type test = "username" | "password" | ["isAbove18", boolean] | ["photo", File];
```

In above type where only `string`(the name of the input field is given) its type should be set to `string`. I have generic type for that

```
type AddDefaultValues<Data extends InputData> = Data extends string ? [Data, string] : Data 
//AddDefaultValues<test> = ["username", string]| ["password", string] | ["isAbove18", boolean] | ["photo", File]
```

Now my requirement is to map above type to an object like below.

```
{username: string, password: string, isAbove18: boolean, photo: File}
```

I am trying from a long time but can't make out anything. Kindly help me out with this...

Comment: can't you just create a new object and assign the properties from `test`? like `{username: test.username... etc}`, you might need to format the values though... would be better to see an example of what you are doing and isn't working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an object mapping with key renaming:

```js
type test = "username" | "password" | ["isAbove18", boolean] | ["photo", File];

type ObjMap = {
  [K in test as K extends [infer F, infer _] ? F : K]: K extends [infer _, infer S] ? S : string;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7CgXigIgK5wgJwHYEMBbCVKAHzTHzjgHcB7bAE1IoG1UBLOAQQCN6ANwgBGAByoANFAH0ANhHy4AuuSgcwAC3rB6UqADFOC5QG4AUOYD0VqIXqZoQnFADyfAFYBZfGBj0oLGhgTWDwCHNQSDdPHz8UAG9zKHUAaShOXBh4RGoodIgAD1hcJjh1TIAzFwNpKpcAfVUAfkMoAC585U6C4ohS8rZ67CgGutxqkYBlFqgpjsDgbEyAcwsAX1MgA)

See also:

- [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)
- [Type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)
- [Key Remapping in Mapped Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#key-remapping-mapped-types)